# Android StatelistDrawable causes button to shrink

Tags: android, button, gradient, statelistdrawable

I've got a problem with a StatelistDrawable as a button background. First of all - I MUST create the button background at runtime, because I receive the color values (gradients, border...) via a webservice.
As soon as I add a state for "disabled" button (I want disabled buttons to appear grey...), the buttons shrink!!

I've created a custom class that derives from StateListDrawable ([Sourcecode of my custom StatelistDrawable](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=yQUDSvyV)).

Here are the results... 
http://i50.tinypic.com/2m4ai2s.jpg

I don't know how to achieve this, but I really need a StatelistDrawable that is generated at runtime and supports gradients and rounded rectangles. Can anybody help me?

Regards
Martin

-------------edit---------------

I've forgotten to mention that this issue does't affect all devices/android versions. There's everything fine on LG Optimus 2x (with official ICS) for example. On a HTC Sensation with CM10.1, the buttons shrink after setting the background StatelistDrawable.

For now, I have a stupid workaround (setting a padding after applying the background drawable)...

Comment: Perhaps you can try `setConstantSize(true)` in the constructor of your StateListDrawable - nevermind, that's on the StateListState class, if you can figure out how to set that... they make this stuff pretty difficult to use in a non-standard way!!